# PHP PDF Generation super slow

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

Making a legal document with data from database. The document has 8 pages of small text

So essentially I'm constructing a html (sell.contractpdf) and then passing this dompdf to generate each time the link view pdf is clicked.

This is very slow any ways to make it faster?

```
    $contracts = Contract::findOrFail(session('contract_id'));

    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('sell.contractpdf', ['contracts' => $contracts]);
    return $pdf->stream();
```

Also I noticed that no bootstrap styling from the html document was passed to the pdf.

Comment: As for the styling: DOMPDF (and any PDF generator I know) only supports CSS 2.1. Bootstrap is built on CSS 3.0, which means that most of the Bootstrap styles won't work. This is very clearly stated in the docs of DOMPDF. For you first question, we really need more info. Is the contract a simple entity with 3 variables? Or does it contain 20 megabytes? What is your view? etc.

Comment: View is super long so wont post here. Right now is plain text. Only 3 variables will be entered into it

Comment: "is super long", sounds like performance hit to me. What happens if you remove all the styling? Bootstrap is large and takes time, even if it doesn't render.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention i removed all styling and just had text in there. file has 15,000 words

Comment: Well, let's say every word needs about 0.002 seconds on average to be rendered ([because strings are hard](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)). 15000 * 0.002 = 30 seconds. Even if you have a CPU that can do it in 0.0002 seconds (which is 5000 words per second!), it still takes 3 seconds, which seems like ages on a website.

Comment: How long does it takes to render the view in HTML? Does the view contain images?

Comment: @Ruben no images, pretty much instant in html

Comment: @Loek maybe I can look into joining that part to another pdf which has info added dynamically

Comment: Ok. Try one page at a time to see wich page might cause the performance drop.

Comment: You can also try to record the generated HTML to a file and to generate a PDF from it, you'll see how much time it takes only for the PDF generation.